# changing SSL certificates to a different location

Tags: ssl, curl, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

Currently we read from HTTPS using cURL. Everything works fine.

We set up certficates in curl as follows:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE,"PEM");
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_SSLCERT,"/etc/ssl/certs/abc.cert.pem");

curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE,"PEM");
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_SSLKEY,"/etc/ssl/certs/abc.key.pem");
```

Now we want to move these certificate files to a different directory. Even if I change the path in the commands above it does not work because I think the certificate path is hard coded as /etc/ssl in libcurl.

Based on googling I tried adding first,

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAPATH, "/MyDir/");
```

and then the four lines with the correct relative path. It didnt work.

How to change the path (the directory where the certificates are stored) into something I want. Example or explanation will be appreciated.

Thanks

James

Answer (score 6):

No, there's no hardcoded paths for client certificates at all in libcurl, your theory is incorrect.

But your mixing of the [CURLOPT_SSLCERT](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLCERT.html) option (which is for client certificates) and the [CURLOPT_CAPATH](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CAPATH.html) option (which is for CA certs) in the same question here, might imply that you've misunderstood what the options really are and do.

The capath/bundle has a hardcoded default within libcurl, but you can always set your own preferred one with one of the the CA* options.