# configuring CA path on Heroku with curb gem

Tags: ruby, ssl, curl, heroku

I'm getting a Curl::Err::SSLCaertBadFile when I try to access the SendGrid API using the newslettre gem.

The gem uses the curb gem to wrap libcurl. I found this piece that made me think I needed to set the ca_path [SSLCaertBadFile error heroku curb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154679/sslcaertbadfile-error-heroku-curb) , and then I found this one [changing SSL certificates to a different location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976511/changing-ssl-certificates-to-a-different-location) which helped me find the name of that variable in libcurl. curb lets you set options using this interface: https://github.com/taf2/curb/blob/master/lib/curl/easy.rb#L27 . Based on this and the sym2curl method below it, I tried each of these configurations:

```
curl.set(Curl::CURLOPT_CAPATH, "/etc/ssl/certs") 
curl.set(:capath, "/etc/ssl/certs")
```

But each time I tried to hit the secure api I got the same error.